# Congruence solution $2^{14}= x (mod 17)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How to solve the following congruence using properties.

$2^{14}=x (mod 17) $

I got the answer 13 using manual calculation.
Thank in advance.

Comment: I would classify all the procedures to compute a remainder class of $2^{14}$ modulo $17$ as "manual calculations".

Answer (score 2):

Use fermat's little theorem, you only get $2^{16} \equiv 1 \space \mod 17$
It is not much use for this question.

So I just use $2^4 \equiv -1 \space \mod 17$ ,manual calculation like you.

$2^{14} \equiv (-1)^3 \times 2^2 \equiv -4 \equiv 13 \space \mod 17$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).